# webpack HtmlWebpackPlugin is not a constructor?

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

package.json

```
   {
      "name": "test2",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "webpack.config.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "build": "webpack"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
        "webpack": "^5.1.3",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.1.0"
      }
    }
```

webpack.config.js

```
const {resolve} = require('path');
const {HtmlWebpackPlugin} = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'built.js',
        path: resolve(__dirname, 'build')
    },
 
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template: './src/webpack.html'})
    ],
    mode: 'development'
};
```

My Error:

```
[webpack-cli] TypeError: HtmlWebpackPlugin is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\webpack workspace\test2\webpack.config.js:16:9)
    at Module._compile (D:\webpack workspace\test2\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:194:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
    at require (D:\webpack workspace\test2\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at requireConfig (D:\webpack workspace\test2\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\groups\ConfigGroup.js:73:18)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

I am curious about why the error message "HtmlWebpackPlugin is not a constructor!" WHY?
I am curious about why the error message "HtmlWebpackPlugin is not a constructor!" WHY?
I am curious about why the error message "HtmlWebpackPlugin is not a constructor!" WHY?

Answer (score 5):

Shouldn't it be like this?

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
```